# C' UWP => different AppbarButton.Flyout behaviour TargetVersion 1809 vs. 1903

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I recently ran into trouble with my Commandbar. 
With targetversion 1809 the flyout of my appbarbutton is shown correctly on top of the screen. Switching to targetversion 1903 my flyout is opened behind the scondaryitems panel

Any help, tip, advise is welcome... thank you

Below the xaml. Nothing special plain standard:

```
  <Grid>
    <CommandBar Background="Transparent" IsOpen="False" DefaultLabelPosition="Right" >
      <AppBarButton Icon="Add" Label="Add"/>
      <AppBarButton Icon="Edit" Label="Edit"/>
      <AppBarButton Icon="Share" Label="Share"/>
      <CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
         <AppBarButton Icon="Setting" Label="Settings">
            <AppBarButton.Flyout>
               <Flyout >
                 <Slider />
               </Flyout>
             </AppBarButton.Flyout>
           </AppBarButton>
         <AppBarButton Icon="Add" Label="Button 1">
           <AppBarButton.KeyboardAccelerators>
             <KeyboardAccelerator Modifiers="Control" Key="N" />
           </AppBarButton.KeyboardAccelerators>
         </AppBarButton>
         <AppBarButton Icon="Delete" Label="Button 2">
           <AppBarButton.KeyboardAccelerators>
              <KeyboardAccelerator Key="Delete" />
           </AppBarButton.KeyboardAccelerators>
         </AppBarButton>
         <AppBarSeparator />
         <AppBarButton Icon="FontDecrease" Label="Button 3">
           <AppBarButton.KeyboardAccelerators>
              <KeyboardAccelerator Modifiers="Control" Key="Subtract" />
           </AppBarButton.KeyboardAccelerators>
          </AppBarButton>
          <AppBarButton Icon="FontIncrease" Label="Button 4">
            <AppBarButton.KeyboardAccelerators>
              <KeyboardAccelerator Modifiers="Control" Key="Add" />
            </AppBarButton.KeyboardAccelerators>
          </AppBarButton>
        </CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
    </CommandBar>
  </Grid>
```

[image: targetversion 1809]
[image: targetversion 1903]

Comment: That's interesting, I need to do more testing to confirm this. Please roll back to 1809 temporarily. And I will update below if I get any information.

Comment: I guess it has something to do with the new introduced "shadow"?!